# VAE-307 GSM GPS pager is not answering the 0008 command

Tags: gps, sms, gsm

My boss got 2 gsm devices for gps, device 2 is simple, it gets a call and it sends out a sms with the geolocation (google earth formatted). However, it is lacking some other features, so my boss asked me to work with device one: VAE-307, from Vision. So far, it looks quite easy: a) use a phone to write 7 contacts to a GSM sim card, each contact has a to be the  user/id, and the phone number to call if there's an event. No mistery there. Field #4 is slightly different, it is just the password for the commands, and 'name' field is to remain blank.  Once you have the 7 contacts, you put the sim card in the gps and you power it on. With a phone as gateway, I will develop a software to page the gps and generate a report with the answers.

To request an action, you just type and send a sms like this: "# password # 000X", where password is the 4 digits password on position 4, and the X is a number from 1 to 8.  So far, the command we are testing is 0008, which will get the geolocation via sms.

Here comes the problem. I use my pc to connect via Bluetooth to a regular phone, and I issue the AT commands like this:

```
AT+CMGF=1 [ENTER]
OK
AT+CMGS="NUMBER" [ENTER]
> #PASS# 0008 [CTRL + Z]
+CMGS: 71
OK
```

As you may know, format is text per the first line, 'number' belongs to the destination, 71 is the confirmation number. I verified that the message gets sent/received.  My concern goes to the line '#PASS# 0008. I can tell the message has been sent.  I know it is received. I am not sure if every single one gets read at the gps. Yet, I am not receiving reply. Not a single one.

This is what I have done so far: the excuse for a manual provided with the device says (and I am quoting):

**Name: N/A**

**Number: # password #**

**The password is 4 digit Arabic numerals code, giving access to use SMS to control some system function in vehicle.**

So, I wasn't sure if '#' or the blank space were suppose to be included with the password or not. The example DOES include the '#' with this format: '#5566#', but the blank space is not present. Later on, a list of examples is provided, the one I'm after looks like this:

```
# Password # 0008
```

So, again, I'm not sure if '#' is part of the password declaration, or if it is to stress the fact the field is numeric or if it has to be there when sending the message. Nevertheless, the first approach I had (password = '#5566#', command = '#5566# 0008') did not work, I got no reply. So I tried different combinations:

```
#5566#0008
# 5566 # 0008
#5566 #0008
5566 0008
1 5566 1 0008 (assuming '#' meant I needed the number for the contact on memory)
```

And I also tried the sim card with '#5566#' and '5566'. Please notice that the format on the manual adds a blank space between '#' and 'password', but that is not possible when writting a number on the sim card, the phone won't let you, and trying to write it with the AT command will not do it, either.  At this point, I thought it could be the format, so I tried sending it with PDU instead of text, and the gps converted it to the text format, so I said exactly the same as the original message.  Message Format discarded as the root for the problem.

So I went out to find help on the manufacturer's web, no surprise there: http://www.visionsecurity.com.tw/ has no software download or updated manual listed, furter web research gave me http://www.visionsecurity.com.tw/upload/file/23_file_1_cht.pdf (not shown in the website) which is the manual... in Chinesse. With the aid of Google Translator, I managed to find out that both of the versions contain pritty much the same lack of information. And I found no other human with the same problem.

Final details: the device has some wires to check the car alarm and doors status, if you give ground voltage to some of them, sms will be send with the proper location. If the alarm switch gets pressed, sms will be received, and a phone call will be stablished, so I know the gsm service is working there, and if you check the sim card, you can find the sms with the password, so the device is receiving them.

The question is: does anyone know the correct way to program this VAE-307 Quad-Band GSM & GPS Pager Kit device to have it sending a SMS reply with its geolocation whenever I send a request for it?

Thank you all in advance.